# How do i combine these media query in to one?

Tags: html, css

ok so this is a dumb question and i'm blacking out or something but how do i take this media and make it so it will know the screen size automatically?

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .wm-booking-enduser-logo-bg {
    max-width:600px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .wm-booking-enduser-logo-bg {
    max-width:500px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .wm-booking-enduser-logo-bg {
    max-width:400px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .wm-booking-enduser-logo-bg {
    max-width:300px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 200px) {
  .wm-booking-enduser-logo-bg {
    max-width:200px;
  }
}
```

Comment: is `.wm-booking-enduser-logo-bg` direct child of <body>` tag?

Comment: Try adding max-width:100% and combine media query using "and".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like, all you want to do is have `.wm-booking-enduser-logo-bg` expand to the full width of the viewport, automatically. If this element is not a child of a parent element that is restricting the size, simply use the following (without any media queries):

```
.wm-booking-enduser-logo-bg {
    max-width: 100%
}
```

Add a comment if this doesn't work for you.

Edit: Note that `max-width` is different from `width`. The latter sets the width explicitly (*ie* `.wm-booking-enduser-logo-bg` will always be full width). The former means "don't stretch this element past it's regular size, but shrink it if it gets larger than *some-size*".

Comment: in the end the problem was that parent div's was restricting the size.. then the max-width:100%; worked